# Drupal, mysql server settings

Tags: php, mysql, database, drupal

I've a problem to configure database settings in Drupal. I will propose here some sample data:

```
Database Mysql:
Database: databaseName
User: user
Password: password
Server: server.com
Server Choice: mysqldb2 (in phpmyadmin I have this option and I can choose between mysqldb1 and mysqldb2 to access to the mysql server)
```

The error message I get is:

> The mysql error was: Access denied for
>   user: 'user@localhost' (Using
>   password: YES).

I've tried the following lines in settings.php but I always get the same error message:

```
$db_url = 'mysql://user:password@localhost/databaseName'; 
$db_url = 'mysql://user:password@localhost/databaseName/mysqldb2';
```

The user and password work in phpmyadmin so I'm sure they are correct.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
$db_url = 'mysql://user:password@server.com/databaseName';
```

or

```
$db_url = 'mysql://user:password@mysqldb2/databaseName';
```

Answer (score 0):

`server.com`? I think you must change `localhost` to `server.com` in your string.

```
$db_url = 'mysql://user:password@server.com/databaseName';
```